# Поворот ImageView в Android Studio

Tags: android, imageview

Мне нужно повернуть изображение на определенное кол-во градусов после нажатия кнопки. И еще одно изображение должно поворачиваться на градус, соответствующий переменной. К примеру int rotate=20; - изображение должно повернуться на 20 градусов. Канву рисовать не хочу, у меня плохо с этим. Нашел способы вращения ImageView по нажатию кнопки через res/anim, но там я так понял, что чисто готовую анимацию пишешь, например, поворот на 180 градусов. А если мне сейчас только на 50 надо, то новую анимацию создавать? И нашел, как в xml задать поворот, но как обрабатывать через кнопку или переменную я не понимаю. Да и с этим, возможно, я тоже не особо разобрался. Но в любом случае, если поняли, подкиньте идею или ссылочку, куда копать

Comment: нашел кое-что. если в OnCreate пишу строчку image.setRotation(45); , то изображение при запуске повернуто на 45 градусов. А если вешаю это на кнопку, то крашится все ((

Comment: ребята спасибо) никто не ответил, но я сам ответил. после того как спрашиваешь, сразу же сам ответ находишь. крч, может кому надо будет. засунул кнопку в onCreate, по нажатию кнопки выполняется image.setRotation(нужный градус). Не работало, потому что я даун и случайно вынес findViewById за пределы onCreate. Не так все сложно. Всем спасибо, занавес

Answer (score 2):

Можно не завязываться на XML-анимацию, и использовать [`ViewPropertyAnimator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html).
Получить его можно из любого наследника класса `View` с помощью метода [`animate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#animate()). Поддерживается с **API-12**.

Пример использования для поворота изображения на 180 градусов:

```
imageView.animate().rotation(180);
```

Comment: Почему можно использовать 1 раз? *Метод кнопки: `imageView.animate().rotation(180);` Нажал - только один раз повернулось, 2 раз не хочет)